# How to set up apparmor for Bind DNS?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, chroot

I have figured that on my server apparmor was preventing me from running Bind in chrooted environment. I have created folder `/chroot/named` with all of the directories and files that Bind requires in order to work properly and as such (chrooted) works fine when I disable apparmor for Bind (named).

However, I think it would be nice to set up apparmor so I have both security mechanisms in place.

I have tried by adding following lines to the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` config file and restarting the apparmor service but after that Bind won't start:

```
/chroot/named/** lrwmk,
/chroot/named/ lrwmk,
/chroot/named/* lrwmk,
```

I didn't know which variation was correct one so I have put all three of them because I saw first two without and with double * in the same config file for other paths when Bind is not chrooted and added a third one with single * just in case but it didn't work.

After restarting Bind no errors are shown but when I checked with `systemctl status named.service` or `systemctl status bind9.service` it says:

```
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-18 17:26:48 CET; 14s ago
Docs: man:named(8)
Process: 17739 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 17739 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Feb 18 17:26:48 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Started BIND Domain Name Server.
Feb 18 17:26:48 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 named[17739]: named: chroot(): Permission denied
Feb 18 17:26:48 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: named.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 17:26:48 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What do I need to do with apparmor in order to get chrooted Bind to work normally?

Comment: What does your Google research show? You are expected to do research prior to asking a question and include that research in the question and any problems you have implementing  the research.

Comment: I just found 1 comment saying to use /chroot/named/** rw which I also tried before but it didn't work so I added these three that also don't work. 0 tutorials or documentation on how to set up chrooted bind with apparmor